# NodeMCU ESP-12E Wont Print to Serial in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, kinematics, motion-planning, gyroscope, accelerometer

So, im using a ESP-12E nothing special about it, to try and run this code i found from a custom library example.

```
/* ============================================
I2Cdev device library code is placed under the MIT license
Copyright (c) 2012 Jeff Rowberg

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.
===============================================
*/

/* This driver reads quaternion data from the MPU6060 and sends
   Open Sound Control messages.

  GY-521  NodeMCU
  MPU6050 devkit 1.0
  board   Lolin         Description
  ======= ==========    ====================================================
  VCC     VU (5V USB)   Not available on all boards so use 3.3V if needed.
  GND     G             Ground
  SCL     D1 (GPIO05)   I2C clock
  SDA     D2 (GPIO04)   I2C data
  XDA     not connected
  XCL     not connected
  AD0     not connected
  INT     D8 (GPIO15)   Interrupt pin

*/

#if defined(ESP8266)
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#else
#include <WiFi.h>
#endif
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <OSCMessage.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>         //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager

// I2Cdev and MPU6050 must be installed as libraries, or else the .cpp/.h files
// for both classes must be in the include path of your project
#include "I2Cdev.h"

#include "MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h"
//#include "MPU6050.h" // not necessary if using MotionApps include file

// Arduino Wire library is required if I2Cdev I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE implementation
// is used in I2Cdev.h
#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
    #include "Wire.h"
#endif

// class default I2C address is 0x68
// specific I2C addresses may be passed as a parameter here
// AD0 low = 0x68 (default for SparkFun breakout and InvenSense evaluation board)
// AD0 high = 0x69
MPU6050 mpu;
//MPU6050 mpu(0x69); // <-- use for AD0 high

/* =========================================================================
   NOTE: In addition to connection 5/3.3v, GND, SDA, and SCL, this sketch
   depends on the MPU-6050's INT pin being connected to the ESP8266 GPIO15
   pin.
 * ========================================================================= */

// MPU control/status vars
bool dmpReady = false;  // set true if DMP init was successful
uint8_t mpuIntStatus;   // holds actual interrupt status byte from MPU
uint8_t devStatus;      // return status after each device operation (0 = success, !0 = error)
uint16_t packetSize;    // expected DMP packet size (default is 42 bytes)
uint16_t fifoCount;     // count of all bytes currently in FIFO
uint8_t fifoBuffer[64]; // FIFO storage buffer

// orientation/motion vars
Quaternion q;           // [w, x, y, z]         quaternion container
VectorInt16 aa;         // [x, y, z]            accel sensor measurements
VectorInt16 aaReal;     // [x, y, z]            gravity-free accel sensor measurements
VectorInt16 aaWorld;    // [x, y, z]            world-frame accel sensor measurements
VectorFloat gravity;    // [x, y, z]            gravity vector


// uncomment "OUTPUT_READABLE_QUATERNION" if you want to see the actual
// quaternion components in a [w, x, y, z] format (not best for parsing
// on a remote host such as Processing or something though)
#define OUTPUT_READABLE_QUATERNION

// uncomment "OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER" if you want to see Euler angles
// (in degrees) calculated from the quaternions coming from the FIFO.
// Note that Euler angles suffer from gimbal lock (for more info, see
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)
//#define OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER

// uncomment "OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL" if you want to see the yaw/
// pitch/roll angles (in degrees) calculated from the quaternions coming
// from the FIFO. Note this also requires gravity vector calculations.
// Also note that yaw/pitch/roll angles suffer from gimbal lock (for
// more info, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)
//#define OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL

// uncomment "OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL" if you want to see acceleration
// components with gravity removed. This acceleration reference frame is
// not compensated for orientation, so +X is always +X according to the
// sensor, just without the effects of gravity. If you want acceleration
// compensated for orientation, us OUTPUT_READABLE_WORLDACCEL instead.
//#define OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL

// uncomment "OUTPUT_READABLE_WORLDACCEL" if you want to see acceleration
// components with gravity removed and adjusted for the world frame of
// reference (yaw is relative to initial orientation, since no magnetometer
// is present in this case). Could be quite handy in some cases.
#define OUTPUT_READABLE_WORLDACCEL

// uncomment "OUTPUT_TEAPOT_OSC" if you want output that matches the
// format used for the InvenSense teapot demo
//#define OUTPUT_TEAPOT_OSC


#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER
float euler[3];         // [psi, theta, phi]    Euler angle container
#endif
#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL
float ypr[3];           // [yaw, pitch, roll]   yaw/pitch/roll container and gravity vector
#endif

#define INTERRUPT_PIN 15 // use pin 15 on ESP8266

const char DEVICE_NAME[] = "mpu6050";

WiFiUDP Udp;                                // A UDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
const IPAddress outIp(192, 168, 1, 11);     // remote IP to receive OSC
const unsigned int outPort = 9999;          // remote port to receive OSC

// ================================================================
// ===               INTERRUPT DETECTION ROUTINE                ===
// ================================================================

volatile bool mpuInterrupt = false;     // indicates whether MPU interrupt pin has gone high
void dmpDataReady() {
    mpuInterrupt = true;
}

void mpu_setup()
{
  // join I2C bus (I2Cdev library doesn't do this automatically)
#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(400000); // 400kHz I2C clock. Comment this line if having compilation difficulties
#elif I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE
  Fastwire::setup(400, true);
#endif

  // initialize device
  Serial.println(F("Initializing I2C devices..."));
  mpu.initialize();
  pinMode(INTERRUPT_PIN, INPUT);

  // verify connection
  Serial.println(F("Testing device connections..."));
  Serial.println(mpu.testConnection() ? F("MPU6050 connection successful") : F("MPU6050 connection failed"));

  // load and configure the DMP
  Serial.println(F("Initializing DMP..."));
  devStatus = mpu.dmpInitialize();

  // supply your own gyro offsets here, scaled for min sensitivity
  mpu.setXGyroOffset(220);
  mpu.setYGyroOffset(76);
  mpu.setZGyroOffset(-85);
  mpu.setZAccelOffset(1788); // 1688 factory default for my test chip

  // make sure it worked (returns 0 if so)
  if (devStatus == 0) {
    // turn on the DMP, now that it's ready
    Serial.println(F("Enabling DMP..."));
    mpu.setDMPEnabled(true);

    // enable Arduino interrupt detection
    Serial.println(F("Enabling interrupt detection (Arduino external interrupt 0)..."));
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(INTERRUPT_PIN), dmpDataReady, RISING);
    mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();

    // set our DMP Ready flag so the main loop() function knows it's okay to use it
    Serial.println(F("DMP ready! Waiting for first interrupt..."));
    dmpReady = true;

    // get expected DMP packet size for later comparison
    packetSize = mpu.dmpGetFIFOPacketSize();
  } else {
    // ERROR!
    // 1 = initial memory load failed
    // 2 = DMP configuration updates failed
    // (if it's going to break, usually the code will be 1)
    Serial.print(F("DMP Initialization failed (code "));
    Serial.print(devStatus);
    Serial.println(F(")"));
  }
}

void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(F("\nOrientation Sensor OSC output")); Serial.println();

  //WiFiManager
  //Local intialization. Once its business is done, there is no need to keep it around
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  //reset saved settings
  //wifiManager.resetSettings();

  //fetches ssid and pass from eeprom and tries to connect
  //if it does not connect it starts an access point with the specified name
  //and goes into a blocking loop awaiting configuration
  wifiManager.autoConnect(DEVICE_NAME);

  Serial.print(F("WiFi connected! IP address: "));
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  mpu_setup();
}

void mpu_loop()
{
  // if programming failed, don't try to do anything
  if (!dmpReady) return;

  // wait for MPU interrupt or extra packet(s) available
  if (!mpuInterrupt && fifoCount < packetSize) return;

  // reset interrupt flag and get INT_STATUS byte
  mpuInterrupt = false;
  mpuIntStatus = mpu.getIntStatus();

  // get current FIFO count
  fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

  // check for overflow (this should never happen unless our code is too inefficient)
  if ((mpuIntStatus & 0x10) || fifoCount == 1024) {
    // reset so we can continue cleanly
    mpu.resetFIFO();
    Serial.println(F("FIFO overflow!"));

    // otherwise, check for DMP data ready interrupt (this should happen frequently)
  } else if (mpuIntStatus & 0x02) {
    // wait for correct available data length, should be a VERY short wait
    while (fifoCount < packetSize) fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

    // read a packet from FIFO
    mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);

    // track FIFO count here in case there is > 1 packet available
    // (this lets us immediately read more without waiting for an interrupt)
    fifoCount -= packetSize;

#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_QUATERNION
    // display quaternion values in easy matrix form: w x y z
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    Serial.print("quat\t");
    Serial.print(q.w);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(q.x);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(q.y);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(q.z);
#endif

#ifdef OUTPUT_TEAPOT_OSC
#ifndef OUTPUT_READABLE_QUATERNION
    // display quaternion values in easy matrix form: w x y z
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
#endif
    // Send OSC message
    OSCMessage msg("/imuquat");
    msg.add((float)q.w);
    msg.add((float)q.x);
    msg.add((float)q.y);
    msg.add((float)q.z);

    Udp.beginPacket(outIp, outPort);
    msg.send(Udp);
    Udp.endPacket();

    msg.empty();
#endif

#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_EULER
    // display Euler angles in degrees
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetEuler(euler, &q);
    Serial.print("euler\t");
    Serial.print(euler[0] * 180/M_PI);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(euler[1] * 180/M_PI);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(euler[2] * 180/M_PI);
#endif

#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_YAWPITCHROLL
    // display Euler angles in degrees
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(ypr, &q, &gravity);
    Serial.print("ypr\t");
    Serial.print(ypr[0] * 180/M_PI);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(ypr[1] * 180/M_PI);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(ypr[2] * 180/M_PI);
#endif

#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL
    // display real acceleration, adjusted to remove gravity
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetAccel(&aa, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetLinearAccel(&aaReal, &aa, &gravity);
    Serial.print("areal\t");
    Serial.print(aaReal.x);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(aaReal.y);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(aaReal.z);
#endif

#ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_WORLDACCEL
    // display initial world-frame acceleration, adjusted to remove gravity
    // and rotated based on known orientation from quaternion
    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetAccel(&aa, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetLinearAccel(&aaReal, &aa, &gravity);
    mpu.dmpGetLinearAccelInWorld(&aaWorld, &aaReal, &q);
    Serial.print("aworld\t");
    Serial.print(aaWorld.x);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(aaWorld.y);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(aaWorld.z);
#endif
  }
}

/**************************************************************************/
/*
    Arduino loop function, called once 'setup' is complete (your own code
    should go here)
*/
/**************************************************************************/
void loop(void)
{
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("*** Disconnected from AP so rebooting ***");
    Serial.println();
    ESP.reset();
  }

  mpu_loop();
}
```

Heres a picture of my basic setup as code asks

[image: Heres a picture of my basic setup as code asks]

but when i log onto the Serial, nothing shows up, even though ive installed the drivers, wiped the flash, added extra boards library, and everything else. Im super confused and google bears no help either, that's why im here. I can give more if specifically asked for, but other than that, heres a snippit of the log i get in arduino.

```
Executable segment sizes:


IROM   : 284944          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 


IRAM   : 28080   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 


DATA   : 1264  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


RODATA : 3664  ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


BSS    : 30240 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 


Sketch uses 317952 bytes (30%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 35168 bytes (42%) of dynamic memory, leaving 46752 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port COM3
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: 2c:f4:32:3c:71:07
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Compressed 322112 bytes to 230789...

Writing at 0x00000000... (6 %)
Writing at 0x00004000... (13 %)
Writing at 0x00008000... (20 %)
Writing at 0x0000c000... (26 %)
Writing at 0x00010000... (33 %)
Writing at 0x00014000... (40 %)
Writing at 0x00018000... (46 %)
Writing at 0x0001c000... (53 %)
Writing at 0x00020000... (60 %)
Writing at 0x00024000... (66 %)
Writing at 0x00028000... (73 %)
Writing at 0x0002c000... (80 %)
Writing at 0x00030000... (86 %)
Writing at 0x00034000... (93 %)
Writing at 0x00038000... (100 %)
Wrote 322112 bytes (230789 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 20.5 seconds (effective 125.8 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

Any help is appreciated! =)

Comment: start by reducing your code to only send some text to serial, nothing more .... that will confirm if serial communication is working ... disconnect the motion sensor when you do that ... reconnect if serial print works and check serial print again

Comment: @jsotola it just sends this over and over again on the same line:

`⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮ѕ⸮⸮`

it was supposed to say `test`

Comment: that looks like a baud rate mismatch ... change the baud rate in the serial monitor ... if the NodeMCU is continuously sending text, then set the serial monitor to the lowest baud rate, and change it every couple of seconds

Comment: @jsotola in my code, i put `Serial.begin(9600);` in the `setup()` function, so if i change the baud rate in serial monitor to anything else than 9600, it will not display anything. And underneath my NodeMCU board it tells me to put the baud rate at 9600. I might have misunderstood what you were asking me to do though, or maybe you misunderstood my problem, either way, every baud rate seems to print that text, so I am at a loss. Thank you for your respose! :)